# Is there a way to enable the SATA 600 mode in my laptop's DVD bay? (Compaq CQ58-d56SR)

Tags: ssd, sata, compaq-laptop

I have a Compaq [CQ58-d56SR](https://support.hp.com/ru-ru/product/compaq-cq58-d00-notebook-pc-series/5375419/model/5397929/manuals), and I recently upgraded it by installing an SSD into the DVD slot using an optibay.

I noticed that it works in the SATA300 mode while the SSD itself supports SATA600. The laptop's own HDD works in the SATA600 mode. Is there a way to enable SATA600 in the DVD slot, or should I just manually swap HDD and SSD?

I downloaded the laptop's manuals from the manufacturer's website but there is no mention of whether there are separate SATA controllers for the HDD and the DVD bays. I wonder where to get this information.

Comment: That notebook only supports sata 3 according to the specifications here>>>http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03763129

Comment: @Moab - thank you, but where does it say so, on which page? I only can see "supports Serial ATA", with no indication of SATA 3.

Comment: Page 105 (113) under hard drive specifications